# jQuery Accordion in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'd like to use a jQuery Accordion in my Angular application. Because I'm new to AngularJS I just tried to define an accordion in a traditional way and then to use Angular expressions for example inside the h3 (header) of the accordion. This didn't work and I found a lot of posts saying to use a directive and so on. But all the examples seem way to complicated...

In my app.js there is a controller and a variable:

```
    var app = angular.module('appUpdate', []);

    app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', 'http', '$q', function($scope, $http, $q) {
      $scope.applications = null;
      ...
      $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.initAccordion();
        $scope.getApplications();
      }

      $scope.initAccordion = function() {
        $("#acc").accordion();
      }

      $scope.getApplications = function() {
        //...
      }
    }
```

This is what I tried inside the cshtml:

```
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
      <div id="acc">
        <h3>{{applications.length}} applications found.</h3>
        <div>content</div>
      </div>
    <body>
```

Comment: Screw jquery. Check example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Try to make your own Accordion in angular itself.Why you want to use jquery.It is not a good practice to use jquery components with angular and In future when you want too make responsive website then it will be better that you have your own component and you can modify it as per your requirements.